# Sharing connection - IPTABLES

Tags: networking, server, internet, iptables

I've been trying to configure IPTABLES in my server so I can share the internet from the server with another machine. The server IP is 192.168.10.1 (eth0), the connection is coming from 192.168.0.6 (eth0:2), the client is 192.168.10.10 (eth1 in the machine). I've tried using the commands from

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

with the correct changes, but I can't make it work, the client can ping 192.168.0.1 (where the internet is coming from), but it can't access the internet at all.

Server:

eth0 192.168.10.1
eth0:2 192.168.0.6
Currently has connection with both the client and the internet

Router:

192.168.0.1

Client:

eth1 192.168.10.10
Can ping both the router and the server

Comment: The questions seems quiet confusing. Are you talking about connecting to each other over ssh or just opening a port on your system so others can connect to it?

Comment: Sorry, linked the wrong page, the correct one is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit */etc/sysctl.conf* and uncomment:

```
# net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

And the iptables part should look something like below, where eth0 is internet and eth1 is LAN:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

If you have 2 physical network interfaces in server then it should work, you cant use your server as internet gateway if it only has 1 physical interface

Comment: Yes, I only have one physical interface, now I'm aware of the problem, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`? Otherwise you are NATing packets going *into* the private LAN, not coming out of it

Comment: iptables v1.6.1: unknown option "state"